# PHP count the amount of not empty values of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$auflistung = array ($_POST['jacken'], $_POST['hosen'], $_POST['oberteil'], $_POST['tasche'], $_POST['schuhe'], $_POST['accessoireschmuck1'], $_POST['accessoireschmuck2'], $_POST['accessoireschmuck3'], $_POST['accessoireschmuck4'], $_POST['accessoireschmuck5'], $_POST['accessoireschmuck6']);
```

It contains e.g.:

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>      string(10) "1288023365"
  [1]=>      string(10) "1246154493"
  [2]=>      string(0) ""
  [3]=>      string(10) "1293143681"
  [4]=>      string(10) "1293143242"
  [5]=>      string(0) ""
  [6]=>      string(0) ""
  [7]=>      string(0) ""
  [8]=>      string(0) ""
  [9]=>      string(0) ""
  [10]=>     string(0) ""
}
```

Now i need the amount of aviable values. In this case 4

I tried: echo count( $auflistung ); but the result includes allso the empty values, so 11. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not fix the origin of the empty elements and create the array with only non empty values?

Comment: @ZombieHunter has a good point. I've extended my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to iterate over each value. If you don't provide a callback, any key whose value == false gets removed. Empty is close enough to false for PHP.

```
echo count(array_filter($auflistung));
```

ZombieHunter has a good point about creating the array from non-empty values. This is a clean way of doing that.

```
$keys=array(
    'jacken', 
    'hosen', 
    'oberteil', 
    'tasche', 
    'schuhe', 
    'accessoireschmuck1', 
    'accessoireschmuck2', 
    'accessoireschmuck3', 
    'accessoireschmuck4', 
    'accessoireschmuck5', 
);

$auflistung=array();
foreach ($keys as $key){
    if (isset($_POST[$key]) && !empty($_POST[$key])) $auflistung[]=$_POST[$key];
}

echo count($auflistung);
```