# PHP: Dynamically find how many variables aren't empty

Tags: php

I have a list of 14 variables that may or may not be empty. Let's say for example we have many individual variables that holds a select ingredient for a recipe. The number of ingredients in a recipe will differ by recipe, obviously. Is there a way, using PHP, that we can see how many of the 14 variables are not empty (i.e. contain an ingredient)?

**Example (using 7 ingredients):**

```
    $ing_1 = "carrots"
    $ing_2 = "apples"
    $ing_3 = "sugar"
    $ing_4 = "celery"
    $ing_5 = ""
    $ing_6 = ""
    $ing_7 = ""
```

How would I get the awnser `4`?

*Further Info:*

I am using `mysqli_fetch_array` to load to variables.

Comment: if($ing_1 !== '') { // not empty}   .................

Comment: if you do this as an array - `$ing[1]`/`$ing[2]`/etc - instead of your var structure, then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422889/how-to-count-non-empty-entries-in-php-array or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696281/php-count-the-amount-of-not-empty-values-of-array or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672562/how-to-get-only-not-null-element-count-in-array-php could help.

Comment: Disclaimer: This is not PHP, but an alternative with (my)SQL: As you say, that you use `mysqli_fetch_array` I think you got a database in the back. You could select an addional field (count numbers of ingredients) and then just "read" this field where the number of ingredients is saved.

Comment: if you stay with your current var structure, then you could do a loop - `$count=0; for($i=1;$i<=7;$i++){ if(!empty(${"ing_$i"})) $count++; } echo $count;`

Comment: Please add your php code here....

Comment: @Sean if you write that as an awnser I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

given your current variable structure, you could loop over your variable like-

```
$count=0; 
for($i=1;$i<=7;$i++){ 
    if(!empty(${"ing_$i"})) $count++; 
} 
echo $count;
```

with the `$i<=7` could be increased to `$i<=14` if you have 14 variable/ingredients.